# How to stop iterating through the for-loop so the player can move in Python maze game?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I am using Python 3 and I'm very, very inexperienced so please be kind.
I have a maze game which is also a language vocabulary game. Everything works like it is supposed to except one thing. When the player rolls over the "gold" and the question pops up, the `for` loop keeps iterating through ALL of the questions in my dictionary for that language. I want it to only ask one, allow the player to move, and ask a different one when the player rolls over another "gold" for the next question.
The `for` loop I am referencing is here:

```
# Create function to get questions and answers.
def getQuestions(language):
    for qa in dic[language]:
        q = qa['question']
        a = qa['answer']
        ans = simpledialog.askstring("Input", q, parent=root)
        if ans == a:
            print("Great job!")
        else:
            print("The correct answer was...", a)
        screen.listen()
```

I am not sure what to do about this problem. I have my game code posted below. Please let me know how I can fix this problem, or if there is a better way to do this.

```
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen
import tkinter
from tkinter import PhotoImage, simpledialog
import random

largefont = ("Verdana", 12)

# Define function to create Spanish level.
def span():
    pen.setup(level_1)
    player.setup(level_1)
    setup(level_1)

# Define function to create French level.
def fren():
    pen.setup(level_2)
    player.setup(level_2)
    setup(level_2)

# Define function to create Japanese level.
def jpn():
    pen.setup(level_3)
    player.setup(level_3)
    setup(level_3)

# Define function to create Turkish level.
def turk():
    pen.setup(level_4)
    player.setup(level_4)
    setup(level_4)

# Create dictionary.
dic = {'spanish': [
    {'question': 'What is morado/a?', 'answer': 'purple'},
    {'question': 'What is blanco/a?', 'answer': 'white'},
    {'question': 'What is el durazno?', 'answer': 'peach'},
    {'question': 'What is la granada?', 'answer': 'pomegranate'},
    {'question': 'What is la galleta?', 'answer': 'cookie'},
    {'question': 'What is el bistec?', 'answer': 'steak'},
    {'question': 'What is el relámpago?', 'answer': 'lightning'},
    {'question': 'What is el amanecer?', 'answer': 'sunrise'}
],
'french': [
    {'question': 'What is le arc en ciel?', 'answer': 'rainbow'},
    {'question': 'What is la glace?', 'answer': 'ice'},
    {'question': 'What is la cascade?', 'answer': 'waterfall'},
    {'question': 'What is le marais?', 'answer': 'swamp'},
    {'question': 'What is le feu?', 'answer': 'fire'},
    {'question': 'What is la cuillère?', 'answer': 'spoon'},
    {'question': 'What is la bouche?', 'answer': 'mouth'},
    {'question': 'What is le dos?', 'answer': 'back'},
    {'question': 'What is le visage?', 'answer': 'face'},
    {'question': 'What is le chat?', 'answer': 'cat'}
],
'japanese': [
    {'question': 'What is ペンギン?', 'answer': 'penguin'},
    {'question': 'What is 甲虫?', 'answer': 'beetle'},
    {'question': 'What is 蝶々?', 'answer': 'butterfly'},
    {'question': 'What is お兄さん?', 'answer': 'older brother'},
    {'question': 'What is ふうふ?', 'answer': 'married couple'},
    {'question': 'What is 今日は?', 'answer': 'hello'},
    {'question': 'What is 元気です。?', 'answer': 'I am good.'},
    {'question': 'What is わくわくしています。?', 'answer': 'I am excited.'},
    {'question': 'What is 恥ずかしいです。?', 'answer': 'I am embarrassed.'},
    {'question': 'What is 誰??', 'answer': 'Who?'},
    {'question': 'What is 何??', 'answer': 'What?'}
],
'turkish': [
    {'question': 'What is nasıl??', 'answer': 'How?'},
    {'question': 'What is Banyo nerede??', 'answer': 'Where is the bathroom?'},
    {'question': 'What is kitaplık?', 'answer': 'library'},
    {'question': 'What is piyasa?', 'answer': 'market'},
    {'question': 'What is plaj?', 'answer': 'beach'},
    {'question': 'What is fırıncılık?', 'answer': 'bakery'},
    {'question': 'What is kule?', 'answer': 'tower'},
    {'question': 'What is lunapark?', 'answer': 'amusement park'},
    {'question': 'What is taraf?', 'answer': 'party'},
    {'question': 'What is kitapçı?', 'answer': 'bookstore'},
    {'question': 'What is gökdelen?', 'answer': 'skyscraper'},
    {'question': 'What is uçak?', 'answer': 'airplane'},
    {'question': 'What is taksicilik?', 'answer': 'taxi'}
]}

# Create window and canvas using tkinter.
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Language Labyrinth")

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600)
canvas.pack()

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
screen.bgcolor('black')

# Define a function to set flag background for Spanish level
def spanishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("spainflag.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for French level
def frenchFlag():
    screen.bgpic("franceflaggrunge.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Japanese level        
def japaneseFlag():
    screen.bgpic("japanflagoffwhite.png")

# Define a function to set flag background for Turkish level
def turkishFlag():
    screen.bgpic("turkishflagdiagonal.png")

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Spanish level
def combinedSpanishCommands():
    span()
    spanishFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for French level
def combinedFrenchCommands():
    fren()
    frenchFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Japanese level
def combinedJapaneseCommands():
    jpn()
    japaneseFlag()

# Define a function to combine the level and background setup functions for Turkish level
def combinedTurkishCommands():
    turk()
    turkishFlag()

# Create function to get questions and answers.
def getQuestions(language):
    for qa in dic[language]:
        q = qa['question']
        a = qa['answer']
        ans = simpledialog.askstring("Input", q, parent=root)
        if ans == a:
            print("Great job!")
        else:
            print("The correct answer was...", a)
        screen.listen()

# Create function to get Spanish Questions.
def getSpanishQuestions():
    getQuestions('spanish')

# Create function to get French Questions.
def getFrenchQuestions():
    getQuestions('french')

# Create function to get Japanese Questions.
def getJapaneseQuestions():
    getQuestions('japanese')

# Create function to get Turkish Questions.
def getTurkishQuestions():
    getQuestions('turkish')

# Create class with separate window to choose level.
class StartPage():
    def __init__(self):
        # Creation of second window.
        wn = tkinter.Tk()
        wn.title("Welcome!")
        # Creation of game title on start page.
        label = tkinter.Label(wn, text="Language Labyrinth", font=largefont)
        label.pack()

        # Create Spanish level button.
        button = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Spanish", command=combinedSpanishCommands)
        button.pack()

        # Create French level button.
        button2 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="French", command=combinedFrenchCommands)
        button2.pack()

        # Create Japanese level button.
        button3 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Japanese", command=combinedJapaneseCommands)
        button3.pack()

        # Create Turkish level button.
        button4 = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Turkish", command=combinedTurkishCommands)
        button4.pack()

        # Create quit button for start page.
        qbutton = tkinter.Button(wn, text="Quit", command=wn.destroy)
        qbutton.pack()

start = StartPage()

# Create Pen class to draw the maze.
class Pen(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()

    # Create setup so the maze will be drawn.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'X':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)
                    self.stamp()

                    walls.append((screen_x, screen_y))

# Create player class to have a player.
class Player(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='square')
        self.penup()
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('black')

    def bKey(self):
        global color
        print("b key pressed")
        self.color('blue')

    def rKey(self):
        global color
        print("r key pressed")
        self.color('red')

    def gKey(self):
        global color
        print("g key pressed")
        self.color('green')

    def pKey(self):
        global color
        print("p key pressed")
        self.color('purple')

    def yKey(self):
        global color
        print("y key pressed")
        self.color('goldenrod')

    def oKey(self):
        global color
        print("o key pressed")
        self.color('orange')

    # Create setup to create the player on the screen.
    def setup(self, level):
        for y in range(len(level)):
            for x in range(len(level[y])):
                if level[y][x] == 'P':
                    screen_x = (x * 24) - 288
                    screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

                    self.goto(screen_x, screen_y)

                    return

    # Define a function that will allow player to move up.
    def move_up(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() + 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move down.
    def move_down(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor()
        movetoY = self.ycor() - 24

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move left.
    def move_left(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() - 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Define a function that will allow player to move right.
    def move_right(self):
        # Calculate the spot to move to.
        movetoX = self.xcor() + 24
        movetoY = self.ycor()

        # Check if the space has a wall.
        if (movetoX, movetoY) not in walls:
            self.goto(movetoX, movetoY)

            gold_encounter()

    # Check if player touches the question.
    def collision(self, other):
        return self.distance(other) < 5

# Create Question class to create the "gold" in the game.
class Question(RawTurtle):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(screen, shape='circle', visible=False)
        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color('hotpink')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x, y)
        self.showturtle()

    # Define function that will remove gold when collided with.
    def destroy(self):
        self.hideturtle()

# Define function to setup the "gold" in the game.
def setup(level):
    for y in range(len(level)):
        for x in range(len(level[y])):
            char = level[y][x]

            screen_x = -288 + (x * 24)
            screen_y = 288 - (y * 24)

            if char == 'Q':
                questions.append(Question(screen_x, screen_y))

# Define a function for the quit button.
def quitPlaying():
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()

# Game loop in regards to the gold.
def gold_encounter():
    if levels[1] == True:
        print("It worked")
        return
    else:
        # Check for player collision with a question.
        # Iterate through the questions list.
        for question in questions:
            if player.collision(question):
                master = tkinter.Tk()
                b1 = tkinter.Button(master, text="Spanish Questions", command=getSpanishQuestions)
                b1.pack()
                b2 = tkinter.Button(master, text="French Questions", command=getFrenchQuestions)
                b2.pack()
                b3 = tkinter.Button(master, text="Japanese Questions", command=getJapaneseQuestions)
                b3.pack()
                b4 = tkinter.Button(master, text="Turkish Questions", command=getTurkishQuestions)
                b4.pack()
                # Destroy the question.
                question.destroy()
                # Remove question from questions list.
                questions.remove(question)
                screen.listen()

# Create frame where button(s) will be.
frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

# Add questions list.
questions = []

# Wall coordinate list.
walls = []

# Create a levels list.
levels = []

# Define first level.
level_1 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP XXXXXXX          XXXXX",
"X  XXXXXXX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"X       XX  XXX        XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXX   Q    XX",
"XXXXXX  XX  XXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XXXXXX  XX    XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX Q      XXXX  XXXXX",
"X  XXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X         XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X     Q          XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX     XXXXX  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX  X",
"XXX  XXXXXXXXXX         X",
"XXX               Q     X",
"XXX         XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX              X",
"XX   XXXXX        Q     X",
"XX   XXXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    XXXXXXXXXXXX  XXXXX",
"XX    Q     XXXX        X",
"XXXX                    X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define second level.
level_2 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XP  XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XX       XX      XXXX",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX     X",
"X   XXXXXXX  XX  XX Q   X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"X   XX   XX  XX  XXXXX  X",
"XQ         Q     XX  X  X",
"X                XX  X  X",
"X   XXXXXXX   XXXXX  XXXX",
"X   XX   XX             X",
"XXXXXX   XX        Q    X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X      Q      XX   XX   X",
"X             XX   XX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XX        X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX     Q  X",
"XXXXXX   X    XX   XX   X",
"X                 X  X  X",
"X       Q         X  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX  X  X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXX     X",
"X         X             X",
"X         XQ     XXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define third level.
level_3 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"X      X   XP           X",
"X    Q X   X            X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X   XXXX   XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X         Q    XX       X",
"X              XX       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX   XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"X              XXXX   XXX",
"XXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX   XXX",
"X                   Q   X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXX Q  XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXX    XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXX         XXXXXXXXX  X",
"XXX      XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"X            X      Q   X",
"X  Q         X       XXXX",
"XXXXXXX            XXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X Q         XXX       Q X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Define fourth level.
level_4 = [
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX  P  XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX",
"XXXXXXXXXXX Q XXXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXX  Q  XXXXX  Q  XXXXX",
"X          XXX          X",
"XXXXXXXX    X    XXXXXXXX",
"X Q         X         Q X",
"X           X           X",
"XXXXXXXXXX QXQ XXXXXXXXXX",
"X                       X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXXXX      X",
"XXXXXX   XXXXXXX Q  XXXXX",
"XQ                      X",
"X                       X",
"XXXXXXXXXXX   XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXXXX      XXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXXX     XXXXXXXXXX   X",
"XXXXX  Q XXXXXXXXXXX Q  X",
"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
]

# Add the level(s) to the levels list.
levels.append(level_1)
levels.append(level_2)
levels.append(level_3)
levels.append(level_4)

# Class instances.
pen = Pen()
player = Player()

# Creation of quit button.
quitButton = tkinter.Button(frame, text='Quit', command=quitPlaying)
quitButton.pack()

# Button commands for player movement
screen.onkeypress(player.move_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(player.move_right, 'Right')

# Button commands for customizable player colors 
screen.onkeypress(player.bKey, "b")
screen.onkeypress(player.rKey, "r")
screen.onkeypress(player.gKey, "g")
screen.onkeypress(player.pKey, "p")
screen.onkeypress(player.yKey, "y")
screen.onkeypress(player.oKey, "o")

screen.listen()

# Call main game loop.
screen.mainloop()
```

So basically I expect only ONE question to be asked per "gold" in the level. However, it currently iterates through all of the questions in the dict. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Which function?

Comment: @alec_a Apologies. I completely forgot to post the specific code. It is the `def getQuestions(language)` function. I have edited my question to reflect which function I was talking about.

Comment: @Prune I meant to post the specific function. It was a mistake. I'm not sure how to cut down the code so that you can copy and paste it and get the same problem, which is why I included my game code. I have edited my answer though to reflect which function I was specifically referring to.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `if statement` to break out of the `for loop`:

```
def getQuestions(language):
    stop = False 

    for qa in dic[language]:
        if not stop:
            q = qa['question']
            a = qa['answer']
            ans = simpledialog.askstring("Input", q, parent=root)
            if ans == a:
                print("Great job!")
                stop = True
            else:
                print("The correct answer was...", a)
            screen.listen()

         else: break
```

Or more efficiently, you can just break when you want to stop:

```
def getQuestions(language):
    for qa in dic[language]:
        q = qa['question']
        a = qa['answer']
        ans = simpledialog.askstring("Input", q, parent=root)
        if ans == a:
            print("Great job!"); break
        else:
            print("The correct answer was...", a)
        screen.listen()
```

Comment: Thanks! It does allow my player to move again. Is there a way I can get the next question to be different than the previous one? That's my only other problem is that I answer the first one, go to the next "gold" and then the next question is the same one as before. Any ideas?

Comment: I need a little bit more context. Ask a new question about it

Comment: I just asked a new question about it. (: